# How to get hashtag with regex, without breaking the URL's?

Tags: php, regex

I'm currently using

```
$string = 'bla bla bla #hashtag bla bla http://example.com/1-page.html#thisisnotahashtag';

$string = preg_replace("/(#\w+)/", '<a href="search.php?hashtag=$1">$1</a>', $string);

echo $string;
```

**Returns:** `bla bla bla <a href="search.php?hashtag=#hashtag">#hashtag</a> bla bla http://example.com/1-page.html<a href="search.php?hashtag=#thisisnotahashtag">#thisisnotahashtag</a>`

Works good, however it cuts up the URLS too. I have a second replace call, that makes URLs clickable hyperlinks. But with this script, it cuts the URL's up.

Comment: How do you mean, it cuts the URL, any example?

Comment: Well, check the return. It cut the URL up. The regex should simply check, that there are no characters before or after the #hastag. In that case, the regex cannot break the URL up. Sadly, in good in theory, but I cannot make regex, even if my life depends on it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this thing: (I'm not really good with `php`, mostly targeting the `regex` part)

```
$string = preg_replace("/([^html]#\w+)/", ' <a href="search.php?hashtag=$1">$1</a>', $string);
```

Comment: Plug and play. Works just like expected. And also plug and play in the actual project. Thank you!

Comment: Use of `[^html]` is ... pretty bad; It's not even doing what you think it's doing. I imagine you intend to use [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?<!html)`, but even that's rigid and only works for URLs ending in `html`. This regexp would fail for `example.com#foo` or `example.com/index.php#foo`.

Answer (score -1):

```
$string = preg_replace("/(#\w+)/", '<a href="search.php?hashtag=$1">$1</a>', $string, 1);
```

the fourth parameter, `1`, specifies the `limit`.

***`Limit`: The maximum possible replacements for each pattern in each subject string. Defaults to -1 (no limit).***  See [**HERE**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: Sadly, has the same result as in my question.